# Stripe: no such token

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, stripe-payments

I keep getting this error while trying to pay with my stripe integration:

```
Stripe::InvalidRequestError (No such token: tok_19Vh25DGnBus....):
```

Here's my Ruby on Rails integration:

config/application.yml (I use Figaro gem to handle environment variables):

```
STRIPE_SECRET_KEY      :"sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"                                        
STRIPE_PUB_KEY         :"pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

config/initializers/stripe.rb:

```
Rails.configuration.stripe = {
    :publishable_key => ENV['STRIPE_PUB_KEY'],
    :secret_key      => ENV['STRIPE_SECRET_KEY']
}

Stripe.api_key = Rails.configuration.stripe[:secret_key]
```

controllers/api_controller.rb:

```
require 'stripe'

charge = Stripe::Charge.create(    # -> Line of the error
            :amount => price,
            :currency => "gbp",
            :source => token,
            :description => ""
        )
```

In the front-end side I use angular and the module angularPayments:

```
$window.Stripe.setPublishableKey("pk_live_xxxxxxxxxxx");

  $scope.handleStripe = function(status, response){
      $rootScope.loader = true;
      var email = $scope.email;

      $scope.email = "";
      $scope.number = '';
      $scope.expiry = null;
      $scope.cvc =  '';

      if(response.error) {
          $scope.paid= false;
          $scope.message = "The card you have inserted is not valid.";
          $rootScope.loader = false;
      } else {
          var data = {
              'invoice_url' : $stateParams.invoiceUrl,
              'token' : response.id,
              'price': $scope.invoice.price,
              'email': email
          };

          $http.post(URL.url + 'send_payment', data).then(function(res){
              if(res.data.error){
                  $scope.paid= false;
                  $scope.message = res.data.message;
                  $rootScope.loader = false;
              }else{
                  $scope.paid= true;
                  $rootScope.temp_modal = true;
                  $scope.message = res.data.message;
              }
              $rootScope.loader = false;
          });

      }
  };
```

I checked and all the keys are correct and match the account that I'm using...In test mode everything worked fine...what am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, the key was correct but I didn't update the minified js file!